# How to use MSI(Managed Service Identity) with Azure storage emulator?

Tags: c#, azure, authentication

Currently I am using MSI in my code. But when I test it locally I want to use azure storage emulator and blob storage in it. MSI is working well with the cloud storage, but when it comes to the local storage emulator, I don't know how to do it. Because local storage emulator requires fixed account and key. Does local storage emulator supports MSI? How should I use it?
My code is like this

```
const string StorageResource = "http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1";
AzureServiceTokenProvider tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
AppAuthenticationResult authResult = await tokenProvider.GetAuthenticationResultAsync(
                StorageResource, null, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

The storage emulator just uses a local Microsoft SQL Server instance and file system to emulate azure storage. The MSI is just for the azure service that supports Azure AD authentication, which storage emulator does not.

Reference - [Services that support managed identities for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So if I want to use emulator in local, I need to use different code, right?